# CGI-скрипт на C++

Tags: c++, xampp, cgi

Было задание создать игру “Угадай число” в виде web-приложения.

Требования:
При разработке интерфейса web-приложения использовать CSS-фреймворки (Bootstrap, Bulma и т.д.).
Логика игры должна быть реализована на стороне сервера в виде CGI-приложения (языки реализации: С/С++, C#, Java).

HTML, CSS и JS уже готовы и работают, но вот для CGI-скрипта нужен какой-то Web сервер. Скачал XAMPP с Apache но он не компилируют C++. Подскажите пожалуйста как внедрить в XAMPP компилятор C++ или как вообще CGI скрипт компилировать на C++?

Comment: Во-первых, веб-сервер в принпипе ничего не должен компилировать, он запускает уже скомпилированное. Во-вторых, CGI-скрипт - это самая обыкновенная программа, которая читает запрос из stdin и переменных окружения и записывает ответ в stdout, и она компилируется точно так же, как и любые другие программы. В-третьих, использовать Java или C# для CGI выглядит глупо, у них есть свои более удачные решения для веба. В-четвёртых, использовать CGI в 2023 году уже само по себе выглядит глупо

Comment: Система образования, к сожалению, так не считает) возможно это задание чисто для понимания взаимодействия с сервером...

Comment: @andreymal CGI самое то для понимания как работает сервер. И даже весьма хороший вариант для малопользовательских приложений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внедрить в xampp очень просто - положите готовую программу в папку cgi-bin и включите модуль cgi если кто-то его выключил.

Компилировать любым компилятором.